# Old codebase in codeigniter 2.1.4 blocking sessions & ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, codeigniter-2

My sessions are working fine, I have a complex custom user permissions system using TankAuth.  I started this project as a small one, it has turned into something monstrous.  Most of the data is fetched async via javascript frontend.  Its basically an API now, with some exceptions.

My question is in regards to sessions.  I understand that CI 3 (or later version somewhere) changed the session library to allow multiple ajax calls not to block each other.  I have noticed that whilst running multiple ajax requests my application fetches results all together after a delayed time.  I'm convinced this is due to blocking of sessions but i am wary to attempt a fix due to security concerns.

How do i stop ajax calls from session blocking each other without risking security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, I believe you're using the word "block" for two different things ...

Here:

> I understand that CI 3 (or later version somewhere) changed the session library to allow multiple ajax calls not to block each other.

And here:

> I have noticed that whilst running multiple ajax requests my application fetches all together after a delayed time. I'm convinced this is due to blocking of sessions

---

CodeIgniter 3 didn't just change the Session library - it replaced it with a completely new one, and one of the reasons why was for multiple requests not to *interfere* with each other (the first quote).

However, the way to achieve that is to use locking (or what you call "blocking" in the second quote and in your question). And you can't avoid this.

What you can do, is call `session_write_close()` in your requests as soon as they *no longer need to modify the `$_SESSION` array* - that will free the lock and close the session for the current request, but still preserving `$_SESSION` contents for reading.

Comment: Yes your right.  Sorry for wrong terms.  This is where i get too, when can i session_write_close() safely.  Is this done as soon as i authenticate user?

Comment: That's up to you to decide - as I said: whenever you know that you won't be changing anything in `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Well i won't be changing $_SESSION in these circumstances post request so i guess its good to close, right? Thanks for your comments, i see my error in original question once you made me think more about it, thanks.